# What happens with goroutines in aws-lambda when your handler function exits?

Tags: node.js, go, aws-lambda

The question originates in: how much work can I do in the background, when the response has already been sent. For instance: I just want to receive data, tell the client 'ok', and proceed with some database operations that may take some time.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "context"
        "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyEvent struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error) {
        go RecordQuery(name)
        return fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", name.Name ), nil
}

func RecordQuery(name MyEvent) {
        // insert stuff in the database, mark user active,
        // log activity, etc..
}

func main() {
        lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

Can we count on the goroutine to be able to do its work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out we can't assume the code will run.

Example implementation:

```
var alreadyLogging bool

func RecordQuery(name MyEvent) {
    if alreadyLogging {
        return
    }
    alreadyLogging = true
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        log.Print("Still here ", i)
    }
}
```

Behaviour: as long as the container where the lambda is running is receiving requests, the goroutine will be executed. But all code will stop when the container is no longer receiving requests.

Possible output (in cloudwatch):

```
2018/05/16 08:50:46 Still here 70
2018/05/16 08:50:47 Still here 71
2018/05/16 08:50:48 Still here 72
2018/05/16 08:50:49 Still here 73
2018/05/16 08:51:36 Still here 74
2018/05/16 08:51:37 Still here 75
2018/05/16 08:51:38 Still here 76
```

Note that in the Node.js Programming Model, you can request AWS Lambda to freeze the process soon after the callback is called, even if there are events in the event loop: [The Context Object Properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html#nodejs-prog-model-context-properties%20The%20Context%20Object%20Properties).

It would be interesting to see some use cases for this API.

Update: in Node.js, as soon as you connect to databases, you'll have a non-empty event queue. That's why this setting is available.

Comment: As long as the specific *container* (not the *function*) is handling requests. Each invocation runs alone in its own separate container, which the service tends to reuse as often as possible, since that should be faster than constantly creating new ones -- but two concurrent invocations will never share a single container.  In Node.JS, setting this flag is used to allow reuse of things like database connections.  The open connection keeps the event loop from being empty, requiring you to tell the system not to wait for that, but to go ahead and freeze once the callback is called.

Comment: For cases where you need to send a response first, and then do more work, the approach is for the first function to invoke a second function asynchrously -- what Lambda calls an "Event" invocation --  which returns immediately, only throwing errors for things like access denied or no such function.  Lambda discards its eventual output but retries it twice if errors occur at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I've updated my answer to say 'container' instead of 'function'.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but if you're looking for similar functionality (sending a response immediatly and keep processing in the backgorund), you can trigger your lambda from SQS, you get the immediate response from SQS while your lambda works in the background. Bonus you can extend lambda lifetime to 15 min this way